# Creating a user profile via Firebase Cloud Functions with user id as the document id?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm attempting to create a user profile document with the user.uid as the document id, via Firebase cloud functions. I have the following script, but it continues to fail. My hunch is that the syntax is wrong, would appreciate any feedback. Thanks!

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import admin = require('firebase-admin');

// Initialize the app
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// Listen to .onCreate trigger
exports.createProfile = functions.auth.user().onCreate( user => {
    return admin.firestore().doc(`users/${user.uid}`).set({
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: user.email
    })
});
```

Edit: The document itself isn't being created. When I try fetching the user from my Swift app, it returns the following error: `6.19.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] Listen for query at users/6cWCvz30xVZwp8oVpWxSTUUs2TT2 failed: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Comment: "but it continues to fail" is not enough information to work with.  Please edit the question to share the full error as well as the line that generates it.

Comment: Syntax looks fine, but as Doug said, can't give the exact cause without the error. However, the two places I would guess are an issue is either your functions.config() wasn't properly set with your Firebase credentials (check at console with firebase functions:config:get) or the user.email is null and you can't store a null as a Firestore field value.

Comment: The error message doesn't look like it has anything to do with code running in Cloud Functions.  The Admin SDK doesn't generate permission errors, only web and mobile clients.  If you're saying that this code doesn't work, you need to show the logs coming from Cloud Functions, not your client app.

Comment: Hi @KingPolygon , your functions works perfectly, I tried it myself. the error message as Doug Stevenson said is from the client and it's related to permissions so check security rules for your Firestore and make sure they are set right.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue with the firebase security rules. By default they are set to limit access which would cause an `Missing or insufficient permissions.` error